# How to split a list's value into two lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I split a 'time' value into two 'day' 'time' lists?

See attached image:

[image]

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: i try to use dados = dados[dados.time == '2021-04-20 09:04:00'] and iloc but slice a value in the list don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have it as `datetime`object:

```
datos['day']  = dados['time'].dt.date
datos['time'] = dados['time'].dt.time
```

If you have it as `string` object:

```
datos['day']  = dados['time'].str[:11]
datos['time'] = dados['time'].str[11:]
```

Or

```
data[['day', 'time']] = data['time'].str.split(' ').apply(pd.Series)
data[['day', 'time']] = data['time'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
```

Or using `regex`

```
data[['day', 'time']] = data['time'].str.extract('(.*) (.*)')
```

---

To convert it to `string`:

```
datos['time'] = dados['time'].astype(str)
```

It is better then converting to normal list `[str(x) ...]`

---

To convert it to `datetime`

```
datos['time'] = pd.to_datetime(dados['time'])
```

It may use options - ie. `yearfirst=True`, `dayfirst=True`, `format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%I:%S"`

Comment: Thank you for your fantastic explanation

Answer (score 0):

I use this for resolve the problem, is there any cleaner way?

```
dia  = [str(x) for x in dados.time]
hora = [str(x) for x in dados.time]
for x in range(len(dia)):
    dia [x]=dia [x][0:11]
    hora[x]=hora[x][11:20]

dados.insert(0, 'dia', dia)
dados.insert(1, 'hora', hora)
dados.drop(columns='time',inplace=True)
```